# How to autoload a kernel module in Yocto?

Tags: raspberry-pi, kernel-modules, yocto

In Yocto (poky/krogoth), I am building an image for raspberrypi2 using my own meta layer, built upon existing meta-raspberrypi layer.

I want to load automatically the kernel module `i2c-dev` to create the I2C device file `/dev/i2c-1`. It works when `i2c-dev` is added manually to `/etc/modules`. I want to do the same in some Yocto configuration files. I've tried the following in my image recipe:

```
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "i2c-dev"
```

It compiles smoothly but I can't find any `/etc/modules` file, neither any `/etc/modules-load.d/modname.conf`.

Would you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

`KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` is the correct variable, but as it says in the manual:

> You can use the KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD variable anywhere that it can be recognized by the kernel recipe or by an out-of-tree kernel module recipe (e.g. a machine configuration file, a distribution configuration file, an append file for the recipe, or the recipe itself).

This means putting it in the image recipe won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://communities.intel.com/thread/63392) out ...

> I think the answer you're looking for includes the KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD and KERNEL_MODULE_PROBECONF variables:
>
> [Yocto Project Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD)

Comment: `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "i2c-dev"` is enough to autoload a module with no options. However I could make it effective only when added to `conf/local.conf`.