# yocto not including kernel module in final image

Tags: kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, yocto

I am trying to enable the CP210X kernel module in my yocto-poky build. 
I have enabled this option in the `bitbake -c menuconfig <name>`. I have it included in my meta layer config files under the `meta/recipies-kernel/<name>/files/` in the `usbnet.cfg` file also. However, after I use `bitbake <image>` and install the image to my sd card and try to boot, the module does not show up in my `modules.dep`

Performing `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f  -name '*.ko*'`  even only shows a single custom kernel module that I loaded .

In my `conf/local.conf` I have `IMAGE_INSTALL+="kernel-modules"`

My `usbnet.cfg` contains `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CP210X=m`

I know for a fact that these modules are in the mainline kernel and can be used with yocto. Is there some step I am missing?

This is the only warning yocto gives after bitbake, and I dont think its related at all?

```
WARNING: lttng-modules-2.10.8-r0 do_package: lttng-modules: no modules were created; this may be due to CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS not being enabled in your kernel.
```

I'm not sure what other information would be useful but I am happy to provide it. Thank you for any help.

Comment: maybe add `kernel-module-cp210x` to list of packages for your image ? if you are using the core image stuff, try adding it to `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL`. you might need to _autoload_ it too - read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308811/how-to-autoload-a-kernel-module-in-yocto) ...

Comment: I've attempted doing both, and there are no changes. I attempted to add it as an out of tree module as well. This also fails and does not even get loaded into the kernel. I followed the reference manual exactly. Added a .bb file and (prepended with kernel-module).  
Is it possible I am missing a step? I do a commit and push followed by `bitbake myimage`

Comment: run `bitbake -e myimage` and show us the final value of the `DEPENDS` and `RDEPENDS` variables ... (and maybe `RRECOMMENDS`)

Comment: It seems adding the `RDEPENDS` rule into the machine, the kernel, and the meta layer forced the module to be compiled into the kernel in the secondary modules tar. Then adding the `autoload` option to the same `.bblayer` files forced it to be loaded. Iam not sure if it was all three or if only one of them worked, but it is there now. Thank you for the help.